# Toshiba Laptop keyboard printing random characters

Tags: keyboard

I recently bought a Grade C laptop off eBay. It's a Toshiba Portege R30 running Win10.

I have problems with the keyboard. Pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> gives me qa; pressing <kbd>V</kbd> gives me 4rv; pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes a character then plants a ] where it was and <kbd>Escape</kbd> turns on <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

I've changed language to English and region is English. Can anyone help me sort this out?

Comment: If you bought a Grade-C laptop don't expect it to be perfect, probably a cleaning of the keyboard would solve this but it could be also a defect of the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about hw issue on discontinued laptop bought from 3rd party. If simple cleaning + reconnecting don't help you then it is better to buy another one since getting spare parts will be hard.